# Как найти нужный файл в теме WordPress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Нужно найти файл в теме Wordpress, чтобы поменять визуал и расположение блоков на странице (загрузив через дочернюю тему). Конкретно - файл личного кабинета пользователя. Может кто подскажет алгоритм как это сделать или где он может находиться. Тема Sweet Data, если это важно.

Answer (score 4):

Есть плагин [Show Current Template](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/show-current-template/). Ставите его и в админ баре показывает все php файлы
для каждой страницы.

Answer (score 3):

Код, который выводит интересующую вас информацию, совершенно необязательно должен располагаться в отдельном файле. Это может быть функция, группа функций, класс, которые срабатывают по определённым хукам и выводят информацию в нужном месте.

Самый действенный способ найти любой код на сайте - посмотреть в Dev Tools, какие классы html-элементов использованы при выводе, и поискать эти классы в исходном коде. Для этого, естественно, исходный код должен находиться на локальном компьютере, а поиск надо производить с помощью современной IDE, которая индексирует код, так что сам поиск происходит мгновенно.

Далее нужно изучить этот код и в дочерней теме перекрыть шаблон (если он есть) или использовать хуки для модификации вывода.