# Как найти HTML в WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Всем привет !

Есть страница:
https://www.st-bis.ru/catalog/keramicheskij-kamen-blok/
Подскажите как найти HTML этой страницы?

Comment: Нет в WP никакого html в одном месте. Страница собирается по частям, генерируется кодом php.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1125898/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5-wordpress/1125956#1125956

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял суть вопроса, вам нужно добраться до кода странички чтобы внаглую, зачёркнуто, цинично, зачёркнуто, немного его поправить. И тогда да, это не совсем очевидно.
Дело в том, что CMS Wordpress генерирует странички на основе составленных вами блоков и плагинов, посредством PHP и JS кода. Как, впрочем, большинство CMS. Это если вкратце.

Если нужно вставить какой то код помимо как в блоках конструктора, можно воспользоваться каким-нибудь site-wide плагином. Например [Head & Footer Code](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/head-footer-code/). Он бесплатен, прост и удобен. Вот в него можно встроить любой код, хоть свой PHP или JS, ну, и естественно, HTML.

Таблицу стилей (style.css) можно править напрямую через ftp по адресу *[ваш_домен/wp-content/themes/ваша_тема/style.css]*. Или через консоль: Внешний вид\редактор тем.
Рекомендую создать свой файл css а в основном сделать линк на него через импорт (например: `@import url("/css/main.css");`). Тогда при смене\обновлении темы, будет достаточно вписать этот линк и не приписывать все свои стили.

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ - копируете содержимое папки /wp-content/themes/.
И делаете поиск в этой папке по каким-нибудь кускам кода - класс, тег и тп.

Answer (score 0):

Сталкивался с такой же проблемой. В папках будет тяжело разобраться. Если у Вас есть доступ к импортированному или ранее экспортированному .csv файлу от базы данных, то следует открыть его с помощью текстового редактора, найти строчку вроде "INSERT INTO `wp_posts` VALUES ...", далее в этой строчке выполнить поиск нужных элементов по разметке.
Также этот файл доступен в разделе wp-posts по адресу http://localhost/openserver/phpmyadmin/ (в Вашем случае может быть не openserver). Думаю, что там уже сориентируетесь какой элемент Вам необходимо отредактировать.